# How to compile legacy VB6 code

Tags: vb6

We have inherited VB6 dll which we need to make changes to. We have the code but don't have VB6 compiler. How can we rebuild the dll? Where can we download the VB6 environment/compiler from?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can import the legacy VB6 code into a newer version of Visual Studio.

Just open the VB6 project using *File → Open → Convert* and it'll automatically upgrade the VB6 code to the current version.

Comment: ...and the resulting managed DLL built from the project will be incompatible with the rest of the original VB6 application.

Comment: @confuzatron - The questioner obviously doesn't have VB6, otherwise he wouldn't be asking the question.  So why would he care if it's not compatible with the original VB6 app?

Comment: The upgraded code will not be COM compatible in this case so you would have to do some work to make it so otherwise it will be pretty useless to you. Your best bet is to try and find VB6 for sale second hand (or even new) on eBay or similar.

Comment: @Shaul Since a DLL only exists as a component of another program, it's obvious that they care about retaining compatibility.

Comment: @Matt Wilko It's straightforward to configure a managed DLL as a COM component.

Answer (score 18):

VB6 is still available as a part of the MSDN subscription.

Comment: Is this still available to MSDN subscribers?  Can you be a little more specific for those with no VB6 experience?  As in, what is the program/IDE/compiler called?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Visual Studio 6.

Comment: @P.Brian Mackey - At the time of writing, on my MSDN it's called "Visual Basic 6.0, Enterprise Edition (English), Disc 1" & Disc 2

Comment: @Mattl this is still accurate in 2018 thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can get VB6 now, but only by buying Visual Studio 2005 / 2008 and "downgrading".  [Source.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/fdc67d40-f434-49b6-b626-a9c50bf23429/)

Comment: This doesn't address the matter of how you actually get hold of the VB6 install media - AFAIK the only sure way to do this is via an MSDN subscription. Getting it from another source is dependant on old stock and second hand media, or other less legal methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think your eBay regional site - eBay.com for USA - would be your best bet.

However, before buying make sure that your are buyng legal software. Please check the link below:
[ebay guidelines on buying software](http://www.ebay.com/gds/How-to-Buy-Legal-Software-on-an-Auction-Site-/10000000004661417/g.html)
and please make some research regarding relevant copyright laws in your country.

Answer (score 0):

This is the MSDN Subscriber link. You could also search the MSDN site for: "Visual Basic 6.0"

It seems to be [two-disc downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=vb6)