# What is required to run a VB Group Project on Windows XP and Windows 7?

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-xp

I had an application written in VB on my laptop which was running Windows XP until I formatted it yesterday. A friend copied it over several years ago but it's not possible to contact him anymore. This project consists of .vbg, .vbp, .vbw, etc. files and a few .mdb files which store the databases. I also had a shortcut on my desktop which was referencing a .vbg file which used to open up a window and I was then supposed to press a "Play" button to launch the application.

I've copied the required folders over to my new laptop which now has Windows 7 Professional (32 bit) but I have no idea how to run this application and what is required. I also tried creating a VM using Windows XP just to check if the problem is with Windows 7 (or above) but still I am probably missing other required software (a debugger perhaps? visual studio or something?).

My questions are:

- Is it possible to run this project on Windows 7 and what software is required to accomplish that?
- What am I missing on the Windows XP VM? Do I have to install Visual Basic or some other debugging software?

Appreciate your help,
Kyriacos.

Comment: Please change the `vb .net` tag to `vb6` since your question not related to the .net version

Comment: Seems you always ran the software through the VB6 IDE (a product included with Visual Studio 6). If you still have the project files and the source code, hire a consultant who can compile and create a distributable package for you (so that you no longer need a copy of Visual Studio).

Comment: @Matze yes it was some sort of IDE. Can you please let me know where I could find this software (or similar) to be able to do the same job in my new system (either Windows 7 or Windows XP)? Thanks

Comment: @Kyris Visual Studio 6 is available for download for MSDN subscribers; not sure, but I think there´s no other way anymore to purchase it... that´s why I mentioned to ask a professional who can provide help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile legacy VB6 code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229868/how-to-compile-legacy-vb6-code)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have visual basics to run the .vbg or .vbp files. There is no other application that supports those formats. And Second, you can run the project on windows 7 as it is compatible all the way to windows 10.

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you mean by "you need to have visual basics" please? Which software do I need and where can I get it from? Thanks.

Comment: @Kyris It's a little unclear.  When you upgraded, it sounds like you chose the format option which would have wiped out any thing you had installed.  You can get Visual Basic 6 on eBay, but the comment above about hiring a consultant might be your best bet.

Comment: If you have solved your question, please mark it as "answer accepted" to let other users know that you no longer need help.