# How to compile a Visual Basic 6 Project?

Tags: vb6

first of all: I know, VB6 is very outdated but I have to use it to provide support for old versions. Does anyone know, where I can download the required files and afterwards how to compile?

Thanks

Comment: From [What software is available for download?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/software-download-list), you can [See a list of available software titles by subscription type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/software-download-list#see-a-list-of-available-software-titles-by-subscription-type).  In that spreadsheet, `Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise` is available for download if you have the appropriate type of subscriptions. In other words, it is NOT free...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile legacy VB6 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229868/how-to-compile-legacy-vb6-code)

Comment: Visual Studio 6 Enterprise is available from Internet Archive.  I am assuming that it is either no longer copyrighted or the copyright is no longer enforced.  It seems to be freely available for download from a number of legitimate sources.

Comment: Twinbasic is in beta and may be usable enough for what you need, depends on your project. https://twinbasic.com/

Answer (score 3):

VB6 isn't just old. It's so old developer tools were handled differently. Back then you couldn't just find anything you wanted online for free. If you wanted a VB6 compiler, you had to actually buy Visual Studio 6.0, and developer tools were *expensive*: often several thousands of dollars for the premium editions, reaching into 5 figures in today's money.

To this day, Microsoft has never made Visual Studio 6.0 freely available.<sup>1</sup> Moreover, they no longer just sell it. I think you can still get it via certain volume licensing subscriptions<sup>2</sup>, or maybe find a copy somewhere like eBay. Otherwise you'll have to resort to software piracy, which I don't recommend.

FWIW, I think I have a copy sitting on a shelf, but it's not for sale ;)

---

<sup>1 *You can get the basic files legally (I think) via the Internet Archive, but it needs a CD key.*</sup>
<sup>2 *The old MSDN subscriptions still active as late as at least 2016 included* everything, *down to Windows 3.1 install media and keys.*</sup>

Comment: VB6 Enterprise is still included and available in the Visual Studion Enterprise subscription.